# How to get return value from javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I return a value from java script to HTML?

Assume this is my JS file named first.js

```
function getName()
{
var Str= "Vinod";
return Str;
}
```

Now I need to get the value in HTML page. I have included the js file and called the function but I didn't get any value. How can I do the same.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quick example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById("privacy_text").innerHTML  = getName();
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea id="privacy_text" class="terms">
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in your browser's JavaScript console. **Read the error message**. Ask yourself where you expect `$` to come from.

Comment: you using jQuery(document).ready(fu... where is you jquery CDN link <script src="jquery.1.9.1"></script

Comment: I have included that, wait I will edit my question

Comment: Textareas have a `.value`, not a `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Even I tried .value also it doesn't work

Comment: `.innerHTML` also works http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/me9yh/

Comment: If you declare `getName()` in the `ready` callback it works as per the  fiddle in my previous comment. I think that you are not loading `first.js`. Check in the console if the browser is downloading or it gets a 404 error

Comment: @Precious See my ans with use of Jquery

Comment: you still don't need jquery

Comment: @toto How can I check the browser console.

Comment: pressing `F12`...then go to the network tab

Comment: I am working on mobile application

Comment: it's going to be the same in a normal browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did that using jquery .[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/skPxg/2/)

```js
    function callme(){
    return 'success';
    }
```

```html
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.9.1.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#privacy_text").val(callme());
    
    });
</script>    
</head>
   <body>
    <textarea id="privacy_text" class="terms">
    </textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: But My function in another js file

Comment: No problem link that js file in your header using script tag

Comment: I have included still I am not getting anything

Answer (score 3):

**Simply use** `$("#privacy_text").val(getName());`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/me9yh/1/)

Use Like This

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="First.js"></script>
```

Comment: But my function is in another js file

Comment: so what, Is your js is not included in this page?

Comment: included that is first.js

Comment: Now check it will work for you and yes first add jquery file and then first.js

Comment: First add Jquery file, may be there is some code in first.js that call jquery functions